# Cassandra-stress : how to install and set it up outside cassandra cluster

Tags: cassandra, cassandra-3.0, cassandra-stress

I am about to use simple cassnadra cluster (3 nodes, x.x.x.104-106). I'm using CentOS7, so i used datastax repository, Cassandra 3.0. 
I read on forum, it is better to install the cassandra-stress outside the cluster, otherwise it consumes CPU of the node.

Could you please help me, how to install it?

I tried to copied cassandra-stress.sh separately, but it is dependent on some cassandra files (probably created during installation).

So I decided to install whole Cassandra on separate server, in the same network space. Now, I'm struggling with the correct setup, how to run cassandra-stress tool against the cassandra cluster.

In cassandra.yaml I setup Cassandra name, listen_adress to public_ip, rpc_address to loopback address, I set seeds to cassandra cluster nodes (x.x.x.104-106)... but in general it does not make sense to set it up, since I dont wan't create another node in the Cassandra cluster.

Could you please help me?

Edit: Maybe using something like this might be the correct way?

cassandra-stress user profile=/usr/cassandra/stress-file.yaml ops(insert=1,books=1) n=10000 -node x.x.x.104,x.x.x.105,x.x.x.106 -port native= ?
Telnet [cassandra_node_ip_ddress] 7000 works fine

Answer (score 2, accepted):

on every node:
in cassandra.yaml set rpc_address to IP address
in cassanda-env.sh set LOCAL_JMX=no and jmx options autenticate=false 
open firewall port 7199
restart firewall and cassandra

on cassandra-stress server:

```
cassandra-stress user profile=/usr/cassandra/stress-books.yaml ops\ 
(insert=1,books=1\) 
n=10000 -node 172.16.20.104,172.16.20.105,172.16.20.106 -port native=9042 
thrift=9160 jmx=7199
```

Note! JMX communication is not secured

Answer (score 2):

If you have your Cassandra cluster running with the proper ports open (by default 9042 for clients and 7199 for JMX), and Cassandra directory on a different machine, then you should be able to run `cassandra-stress`, from outside the cluster, against your cluster simply by passing the `-node` option with an IP of one of the nodes in your cluster (say x.x.x.104). For example,

```
$CASSANDRA_HOME/tools/bin/cassandra-stress write -node x.x.x.104
```

should work. You can see more options with

```
$CASSANDRA_HOME/tools/bin/cassandra-stress help
```

Comment: Actually, I tried this, I set up firewall for jmx and other ports on all clusters. As you can see my edited in the post, because this idead already popped in my mind, I just got some weird errors. I have to dive into it more. Should I use default seetings for Cassandra? I mean, no changing yaml etc. at all?